# Latitude and Longitude from google's geocoder not working on waze

Tags: android, waze

I am trying to make this link work on waze app:

https://waze.com/ul?ll=-58.440634,-34.611324&z=10

Those are the lattitude and longitude given by google's geocoder with address Felipe Vallese 490, Buenos Aires):

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3Dfelipe%2520vallese%2520490

On the web it points out the location:

[image]

But in the app (clicking the link on an email and selecting open with waze) it says "uh oh could not locate endpoint".

[image]

If i search the address "Felipe Vallese 490" in the app it finds it and let me navigate to it as well.

[image]
[image]

Reading the docs i see there's a search way:

https://waze.com/ul?q=Felipe%20Vallese%20490

In the app it give me the list of results and another tab with "Places", there i can select the location but i think giving this option to users is not very suitable, i think this will be ok if i can make it show "places" tab as default not search results.

I also tried with different lat and long with same results.

What could it be?.

Reggards!

Comment: My god! it took me all day and write this question to see this post: https://www.waze.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1913&t=273227&sid=5e76ad3ccda5c74e19683d29d80f53e2, its because the web ask for lat and lng and app does it by lng and lat 0_0. Yiisus!! I'll leave this question in case another soul suffer this too

Comment: Hey, do you know how can I add multiple addresses?

Comment: I think is imposible in this whay (using deep links) https://developers.google.com/waze/deeplinks/

Answer (score 0):

If you directly want to open the Waze you can read the below link:

https://developers.google.com/waze/deeplinks#navigate-to-location
overall Waze deep link should be something like this format:

```
https://www.waze.com/ul?ll=35.699636,51.337608&navigate=yes&zoom=17
```

Otherwise, if you want to open all navigation apps list and select an application using the below code:

```
val uri = Uri.parse(
    String.format(
        "geo:0,0?q=%s,%s",
        latitude,
        longitude
    ) //result would be like : geo:0,0?q=35.699636,51.337608
)
val geoIntent = Intent(ACTION_VIEW, uri).apply {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        flags = FLAG_ACTIVITY_REQUIRE_NON_BROWSER
    }
}
startActivity(geoIntent)
```